# Installing tomcat policy agent throws zip exception

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, openam

I am trying to install Tomcat policy agent in my machine. I have automated the installation by using `--useResponse` option. However the installation gets completed but in log file i find the following entries

```
[03/08/2016 11:00:37:168 CET] FileUtils.copyJarFile(): Error occurred while copying jar file: /usr/share/suf-sso/bin/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/lib/agent.jar to: /usr/share/suf/tomcat6/lib/agent.jar
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 1609 but got 1611 bytes)
        at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:248)
        at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:177)
        at java.util.jar.JarOutputStream.putNextEntry(JarOutputStream.java:109)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.util.FileUtils.copyJarFile(FileUtils.java:141)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.tools.tomcat.v6.CopyAgentFilesTask.copyAgentJarFiles(CopyAgentFilesTask.java:74)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.tools.tomcat.v6.CopyAgentFilesTask.execute(CopyAgentFilesTask.java:55)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.configurator.TaskRunner.executeTask(TaskRunner.java:105)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.configurator.TaskRunner.runTasks(TaskRunner.java:72)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.configurator.InstallDriver.install(InstallDriver.java:95)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.handler.InstallHandler.handleRequest(InstallHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.admin.AdminTool.dispatch(AdminTool.java:232)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.admin.AdminTool.run(AdminTool.java:135)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.launch.AdminToolLauncher.launchAdminTool(AdminToolLauncher.java:201)
        at com.sun.identity.install.tools.launch.AdminToolLauncher.main(AdminToolLauncher.java:313)
[03/08/2016 11:00:37:169 CET] FileUtils.copyJarFile(): Error occurred while closing output stream for: /usr/share/suf/tomcat6/lib/agent.jar
[03/08/2016 11:00:37:169 CET] CopyAgentFilesTask.copyAgentJarFiles() - Error occured while copying jar files from /usr/share/suf-sso/bin/j2ee_agents/tomcat_v6_agent/lib to /usr/share/suf/tomcat6/lib: invalid entry compressed size (expected 1609 but got 1611 bytes)
```

It is not copying 2 jar files into the location mentioned and throws some zip exception. It doesn't occur when i do the steps manually. Any ideas on this??